# Alternative to system("Pause"); revisited

Tags: c++, system, output

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I have a coding question with it, because a couple of alternatives seem not to work with this code, and I'm not sure why.  If you look right before the return 0;, I'm trying cin.get() and it doesn't stop the program, and neither does my PressEnterToContinue() function that I found somewhere that worked on other programs.  The only thing I've gotten to work with this is system pause, which I don't want to use, since I will also be using this cross platform.  Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PressEnterToContinue()
{

std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << std::flush;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n');

}

int main(void)
{
int pause;
double distance, x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y;

cout << "This program outputs the distance between two points on a plane!" << endl;
cout << "Please input point X1" << endl;
cin >> x1;
cout << "Please input point Y1" << endl;
cin >> y1;
cout << "Please input point X2" << endl;
cin >> x2;
cout << "Please input point Y2" << endl;
cin >> y2;

x = x2 - x1;
y = y2 - y1;


distance = sqrt(x*x + y*y);


cout << distance << endl;

//cin.get();
    //PressEnterToContinue();
    //system("Pause");
return 0;

}
```

Feel free to mention methods of stopping the system that I don't have here.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your last input (`cin >> y2`) leaves the newline in the input buffer. This is then read by your calls to `cin.get()` or `PressEnterToContinue()`.

In the `PressEnterToContinue` function you might want to ["peek"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) at the input buffer to see if there is any characters first, and if there is then do an extra `cin.ignore`.

---

When you do e.g.

```
cin >> y2;
```

And you enter the input

```
123\n
```

Then the input buffer will contain the string `"123\n"`. After the input operator extracts the number (`123`)  the input buffer will contain `"\n"`, which is that the `cin.get()` call reads.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why cin >> y2 is leaving a newline in the input buffer, can you (or someone else reading this explain please?)

Comment: Ok, so I can either use the peek method with the PressEnterToContinue function, or, if I know there's going to be a return character in the buffer, I could also do a cin.ignore() before I cin.get() correct?

Comment: @Slimmons Yes both are okay.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you simply have to flush the buffer. The number `10000` in the example is just the number of characters to clear from the buffer.

```
cin.ignore(10000);
cin.get();
```

And to answer why `cin >> y2` leaves a newline character in the buffer is because you entered a newline character by hitting the return key, and by retrieving the data from the console into your variable you leave the newline character behind.

Comment: why 10000 ? i like this way `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: I just chose 10000 as an arbitrary number.. though I do agree, in my code, whenever I use `cin.ignore()` I do use the maximum number :)

Answer (score 1):

Technical problem: characters (sometimes just a newline) left in the input buffer.

That said, there is never any need for the program stopping itself at the end, so a `system( "pause" )` or whatever stopping action has **no advantage**, and some problems, including portability.

Run your program from the command line.

Or, since you're programming in Windows, use Visual Studio and run the program via Ctrl F5.

Or, place a breakpoint on the last right brace of `main` and run the program via a debugger, e.g. in visual studio by hitting F5.