# system ("pause") in C# won't work. Alternatives?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building a program for the purposes of displaying Smartgraph3 readings. Whenever I start debugging, the command line opens but it then immediately disappears. I know ctrl + f5 works, but I was looking for a solution where I would not have to enter the same command to keep it from disappearing.

I have used System("pause"); but it keeps coming up with a blue line under System, and in the error list says 'System' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'variable'. Does anybody know what is wrong?

Also, I have heard System("pause") should not be used, so does anybody have an alternative that's just as effective?

Here is a copy of my code. Thank you.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using Infowerk.SmartGraph3.SmartGraph3API;
//using CSTestClient.SmartGraph;

namespace CSTestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestAPI();
        }



        static void TestAPI()
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding service_binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress endpoint_address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/SmartGraph3API/APIV01");


            SmartGraph3APIClient client = new SmartGraph3APIClient(service_binding, endpoint_address);

            List<SG3APIDeviceIdentification> device_list = client.GetDeviceList();

            foreach (SG3APIDeviceIdentification device_identification in device_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("device id: {0}", device_identification.DeviceId);
                System("pause");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: (1) not `System("pause")` but `system("pause")` (lowercase!), (2) it's usable in C/C++, and you are using C#, that's a different platform you know! Not just "they say it's different but my program still works", like it's in C and C++. C# is **completely** different from them.

Comment: whoops, my mistake. Was meant to put in C++, not C#.

Comment: You should be questioning your motivation here. You know that CTRL+F5 works, so you already have the "correct" solution. Why do you also want it to work in debugging mode? Instead of artificially adding a pause into your program (which will change the expected behaviour for your end user), use a breakpoint, which is the intended way of getting this behaviour during a debugging session.

Comment: Also, your question is very confusing - your title says C#, your tag says C++, your comment says C++, but your code appears to be C# and you've accepted a C# answer. You're all over the place - what is actually the intended language?

Comment: Editing C++ into the title clarifies nothing, because your code and accepted answer are not C++. I'm now thinking that this is actually a C++/CLI question (being not too familiar with C# myself, I didn't spot that at first). Either way, it is not C++ and should be tagged appropriately (with the C++-CLI tag).

Comment: @JBentley: no, it is not C++/CLI, this is absolutely clearly plain simple C#. I think that the author of this question simply does not "feel the difference".

Comment: But, of course, there's still a possibility that the author wanted to write in C++, but actually had clicked wrong project template in VisualStudio, started writing in C# and did not notice the small differences like usage of `.` instead of `::` and `->`, new keywords, "properties", different syntax for templates/generics, etc. I don't know which one of these possibilities is worse though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go ahead and simply use:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint on the closing brace of your `Main()`. Or use an IDE which streams console output to a debug window which persists after the process exits (e.g., Eclipse, I assume basically anything other than VS). No reason to force everyone who actually wants to run your program the normal way to invoke it like:

```
:; ./myProgram.exe < /dev/null; exit $?
.\myProgram.exe < NUL
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487235.